# How I can use OSM (Open Street Map) locally

Tags: openstreetmap

I am using the following code to retrieve the address from lon and lat:

```
$lon = 100.753; $lat = 13.69362;

function getAddress($RG_Lat,$RG_Lon)
{
  $json = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=".$RG_Lat."&lon=".$RG_Lon."&zoom=27&addressdetails=1";

  $ch = curl_init($json);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0");
  $jsonfile = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  $RG_array = json_decode($jsonfile,true);

  return $RG_array['display_name'];
  // $RG_array['address']['city'];
  // $RG_array['address']['country'];
}

$addr = getAddress($lat,$lon);
echo "Address: ".$addr;
```

My code works very well under ovh server.

My application is installed locally under wamp server.

The same code, does not return anything: What extension or something else that I must activate it locally to have a return of my code?

Do you have any idea, why my code no longer works locally (wamp server)?

Comment: Please respect the [Nominatim usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/). "Mozilla/5.0" is **not** a valid user agent if the request comes from a script!

Comment: How I can have a Valid User Agent ?

Comment: Use the name of your script. It should be *your* user agent, not the user agent of a different software.

Comment: name of my script ? How can I have this name

Comment: @scai : any information please  :)

Comment: You think too complicated. Simply use "med_osm_script v0.1" or something similar as user agent.